# Connecting 2 curved ultrawide monitors to mac mini 2023 via usb-c

Tags: mac, display, usb, mac-mini, multitasking

*I looked for an entire hour for posts related to connecting monitors via usb-c to the new Mac mini, but could not find anything even closely related.
Before I get to this...I shall ask my question.*

In 1 or 2 months I plan to buy a 2023 Mac mini (the base model) since I'm on a budget. If I use both usb-c ports for the 2 monitors only will that affect performance on the Mac mini?

My question is........? will this affect performance and make the machine lag a bit? or will I be able to do these things simultaneously with no issue?

I welcome all advice as well as a recommendation on budget-friendly ultrawide monitors that are usb-c compatible.

thank you kindly.

Comment: Some constructive feedback…why go into the perils of the used marketplace when you plan to buy new?  Tell us what you plan on getting. Focusing on “monitors that connect via USB-C” is like worrying about the trailer hitch and ignoring the vehicle and the load of the boat you’re pulling.  Tell us what you plan to do.  On that note, every single person looking to buy a computer says they will do the same things you plan to do.  Define your jobs (the boat) so you can spec the vehicle (car/truck/lorry) then you know what to get.

Comment: Now that’s out of the way, we need more focus - narrow down to a single, practical problem.  We need more details rather than vague descriptions. Finally, shopping questions are off topic.  See the [Help] for more info.  This question will need a substantial [edit]

Comment: @Allan No worries I got some feedback on Reddit. I'll probably close this question in a few days. forgot i still had this question up lol